# How to Use Overleaf along with Zotero when using IEEE Access Template

Tags: latex, overleaf, ieee

I am currently using Overleaf and I want to create a paper following the IEEE Access guidelines.

These are the steps I followed:

1. I first downloaded the officially recommended latex template from https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/guide-for-authors/submission-guidelines/.
2. Then I created a new Overleaf project and uploaded the zip file.
3. I wanted to link Zotero to add my references to the paper. So I created a new file and linked my Zotero creating a new file called `reference.bib`.
4. I then added `\bibliography{references}` and tried to use `\cite` but what I get is a question mark in a square box like this `[?]`.
5. I then came across https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/In_the_IEEE_for_journals_template%2C_I%27m_trying_to_use_bibtex_for_my_references which I don't understand fully.

- My first question is what are IEEEabrv.bib, IEEEexample.bib and how to get them.
  How to apply `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` without using the .cls file and .bst files as mentioned in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/In_the_IEEE_for_journals_template%2C_I%27m_trying_to_use_bibtex_for_my_references.
- Secondly, how to set up the overleaf project so that once I use `\cite` command, the references get added automatically to the Bibliography section given that it is in the `reference.bib`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the process I used (hope it answers your question):

1. Link your Zotero account to overleaf ([using this process](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_to_link_your_Overleaf_account_to_Mendeley_and_Zotero#Using_Zotero))
2. In the document setup, I have:

   \usepackage{cite}

   \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
   T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

   \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
3. Additionally, I kept the IEEEtran.cls document, it actually doesn't seem to cause any issues despite what [this article](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/In_the_IEEE_for_journals_template%2C_I%27m_trying_to_use_bibtex_for_my_references) says. Honestly, the most useful think about it is the example it links at the end which does use the .cls doc
4. In-text citations can be done using `\cite{the_first_line, 2023}` where the text inside the curly brackets is everything that comes between @type and the comma on the first line of the reference (you'll have to refer to you .bib file here)
5. You can generate the bib at the end (before '\end{document}') using: `\bibliography{references.bib}`